# Need help finding the intersection of two probable events

Tags: probability

A study is conducted on kids about what stuffed animals they have, $15\%$ of the kids don't have a stuffed animal, $50\%$ have a stuffed dog and $55\%$ have a stuffed bear. If one of the children is chosen randomly, what is the probability that a student has a stuffed bear and a stuffed dog?

I'm confused because I don't know how to find the intersection between the events of a child having a stuffed bear and a stuffed dog. How would I go about solving a problem like this?

Comment: Let $D$ represent that they have a dog and $B$ that they have a bear.  You are told $Pr(D)$ and $Pr(B)$.  You are told one additional piece of information... what does that look like in terms of $D$ and $B$?  Using this, can you figure out what is $Pr(D\cup B)$?  Now, using inclusion-exclusion, can you figure out what is $Pr(D\cap B)$?

Comment: @JMoravitz The wording of this problem is problematic.  We know that $15\%$ of kids don't have a stuffed animal, which means $P(B \cup D) \leq 0.85$.  What it does not say that kids only have stuffed bears or stuffed dogs and not other types of stuffed animals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a child has a stuffed dog. 
Let $B$ be a student has a stuffed bear.

You know $Pr(A)$, $Pr(B)$ and $Pr(\bar{A}\bar{B})$.

If you sketch out a Venn diagram, the following relationship will be easier to see.

$$1 = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(AB) + Pr(\bar{A}\bar{B})$$

So after some rearranging we have,

$Pr(AB) = -1 + Pr(\bar{A}\bar{B}) +  Pr(B) + Pr(A) = -1 +1.15 = 0.15$.

The points made by others above are completely true, but I think keeping the scope of the problem in mind, you'd be safe to assume that $Pr(A \cup B) = 0.85$.

Comment: PS: @Kral You will most usually encounter this expression as: $\mathsf P(A\cup B)=\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)$ , and here KuDu has substituted $\mathsf P(\overline A \cap \overline B)=1-\mathsf P(A\cup B)$ and rearranged.  It is a useful expression.  Learn it well.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints/setup**:

Assuming that the only types of stuffed animals polled about are bears and dogs:

Let $D$ represent the event they have a stuffed dog and $B$ that they have a stuffed bear.

We are told that $15\%$ of kids have neither.  Writing this in terms of $D$ and $B$...

from which we can learn the value of $Pr(D\cup B)$.

Then using [Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion_exclusion_principle) and the remaining information we can reach a final conclusion.

> Without this assumption that the only types of stuffed animals are bears and dogs, as @N.F.Taussig points out in the comments above, all we can learn is that $0.55\leq Pr(D\cup B)\leq 0.85$, which means that we won't be able to exactly determine the final answer, but we could give a range of possible final answers using this instead.